# Django плюсы и минусы. Стоит ли изучать?

Tags: python, framework, php, django

Добрый день, форумчане!

У меня такой вопрос, стоит ли слезать с PHP и изучать Django? Если да,
то аргументируйте почему к этому дело идет все в тенденции изучения
языков программирования веб-мастерами? Если стоит изучать Django,
то где можно найти исходники сайтов сделанные на CMS Django и собственное
само описание архитектуры данной CMS? Как говорится, теория - это хорошо,
но практика это лучший учитель программиста.

Comment: > стоит ли слезать с PHP и изучать Django

Это сугубо личный вопрос, но если слезать с PHP - то все-таки на питон.

> почему к этому дело идет все в тенденции изучения языков программирования

Потому что PHP в свое время делался на коленке и до сих пор во многом таким и остается, а время простых веб-приложений прошло.

> CMS Django

**CMF**

> собственное само описание архитектуры

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/)

> Как говорится, теория - это хорошо, но практика это лучший учитель программиста.

Ну ээээ так а что мешает писать?

Comment: >Ну ээээ так а что мешает писать?

возможно, имеется в виду не очень большое число вакансий

Comment: @Fike, меня просто проинформировали неверно, акцент был именно на Django, хотя по сути язык как я понял питон. Судя по вакансиям мне так кажется питон не востребован на рынке работодателей. Где ни читаешь, написано знание PHP, а про питон пишут единицы и то где-нибудь в Москве, а не в регионе... Похоже, все слезать не надо с PHP.

Comment: @IntegralAL, если б это было однозначной панацеей, то вы бы давно уже на нем сидели )  
Несмотря на то, что между языками нет совсем уж драматических различий в возможностях (хотя питон значительно удобнее в рамках классических приложений), на питоне водятся более высокоуровневые и высокооплачиваемые штуки. Потому что так повелось из-за засилия PHP. И в результате у питонистов свой рынок, более узкий, но более дружелюбный (прямо с улицы кого-то сложно взять в замену, да и проекты "сэкономим на всем" пишутся на том самом PHP) и профессиональный.

Comment: @IntegralAL, ну и насчет востребованности в Москве - очень много из знакомых разработчиков работают по удаленке, и не только на российские проекты/студии/агентства. Но для этого, понятное дело, надо состояться хотя бы как начинающему профессионалу.